# Unstyling the contact-info popup in plone.app.theming on Plone 4.1

Tags: plone, diazo

I am creating a new plone.app.theming (Diazo) theme for my site. My rules.xml has the rule:

```
<theme href="theme.html" css:if-content="#visual-portal-wrapper" />
```

This unstyles many popups, but not the contact-info AJAX popup box, which is empty. I can unstyle it using the following rule:

```
<notheme css:if-content="body.template-contact-info"/>
```

but this means that any user visiting that page, and not rendering it in a popup, will see it unstyled.

How can I successfully unstyle the contact-info popup box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The login form popup is wrapped inside a `<div class="pb-ajax">`. Just look at the generated HTML that creates the popup and you will find a class or identifier that you can use to select that particular popup.

On the other hand you can also customize the Plone view that creates this piece of HTML. Though it will be much easier to try to get a class or identifier.